# Examples of Apheretic forms in English?

Tags: apostrophe, contractions

I am looking for a comprehensive list of Apheretic forms in English. I remember seeing in old books words being prefixed with apostrophes which do not require them in modern writing, but can't remember many instances.

Wikipedia provides a list of apocopations but none for apheresis.

Comment: Oh! I went to look at the wikipedia article before reading your last sentence. Are you saying that the example they have are not really apheresis? or that they only belong to a special case of apheresis?

Comment: @Franklin.vp I was just disappointed that there was not a "List of Apheretic Forms" article similar to the page "List of English apocopations." What I'm looking for are some more common words with apheretic origins which I seem to remember seeing spelled with an apostrophe in older books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(The Merriam-Webster New Book of Word Histories, 1991)

> "Aphaeresis has given us a number of new words, like drawing-room
>   (from withdrawing-room), fend (from defend; whence fender), sport
>   (from disport), and stain (from distain). A number are aphetic in the
>   narrow sense: pert (from now obsolete apert, going back ultimately to
>   Latin appertus 'open'), peal (from appeal), mend (from amend), fray
>   (from affray), the verb ply (from apply), the adjective live (from
>   alive), spy (from espy), and tend (from both attend and intend). In
>   the above cases, significant semantic development followed the
>   aphaeresis, so that one does not normally connect in one's mind the
>   shortened and the original longer forms."

More examples in the Wikipedia entry on [Apheresis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apheresis_%28linguistics%29)

> Greek episkopos > Vulgar Latin [e]biscopu > English bishop
>
> English [a]cute > cute
>
> English [E]gyptian > Gyptian > Gypsy
>
> English [a]mend > mend
>
> English [e]scape + goat > scapegoat
>
> Old French evaniss > English vanish
>
> Old French estable > English stable
>
> Old French estrange > English strange
>
> English esquire > squire
>
> Akkadian Ashuraya > Shuraya